# Checking a salted hash against known password?

Tags: mysql, hash, awk, sha512

I've created a mysql dump of my users and passwords and awked them into a presentable form:

Passwords:

```
'6cc5db1c282daa071b0cf80982d19ec0f2e21976a4c39c0c7a3ab30f102b33e2780fd56f4d507e4873630eeb5ba1a8ad8d338bb8abcf64a513630a0dea7044db'
'1927f6acb76f53106a29015ba787e6f7c826f939a64be656a669f78515ffbb2447bee266e5f57751d98f4990f71d131bcb11575199b8e717a0ad91c381df43ca'
'dfd3b2e6478c0ca15102e74251a300abba96296662686f9eeba1f2ebbb9353ad9f91546d0c02ececd5e205c0a94e083a3f63eeec9642f69ad24fd674927c6a3d'
```

Salts:

```
'ecb2796f-e69d-4ad6-858f-832170b00b5c'
'a46a3486-79dd-428b-88a8-558303fe8dc8'
'02b6fedc-6932-4893-8725-cd4c8a191d57'
```

With the first entry on one corresponding to the first on the other. The password for the first entry is password. I am using sha512whirlpool as the encrypting algorithm.

I want to use a utility to encrypt a string ("password" in this case) using that same algorithm and salting it and compare it to the encrypted password. Anyone have any ideas what utility might be good for this? I was hoping to use mkpasswd, but I got an error there:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 password ecb2796f-e69d-4ad6-858f-832170b00b5c
```

And this is the error:

```
Wrong salt length: 36 bytes when 8 <= n <= 16 expected.
```

Was I doing something wrong here? Any advice?

Comment: There are almost certainly metasploit modules for this. In fact, I'd be willing to guess there are more than a couple tools in Kali for this kind of thing. If I were you I'd reask this question on the IT security stackexchange, since it's not particularly relevant here, but the people there will definitely be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks will do. Any answers here are still appreciated.

Comment: Oh, wait... Pretty sure that salt actually is 16 bytes. You just need to decode the hex and remove the dashes.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption.

Comment: So, try `mkpasswd -m sha-512 password $'\xec\xb2\x79\x6f\xe6\x9d\x4a\xd6\x85\x8f\x83\x21\x70\xb0\x0b\x5c'` (the `$` thing is bash string interpolation syntax)

Comment: The presented Salts are 128-bits in [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) format.

Comment: So convert the hex to... decimal? I'm not much of a security guy, you have to understand. Here's the link to the IT sec question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116854/checking-a-salted-hash-against-known-password

Comment: @Parthian Shot, I'm getting a "Illegal salt character '\'." error.

Comment: The `mkpasswd` I have installed doesn't have a `-m` flag, so I'm assuming you're using [this version](http://www.man-online.org/page/1-mkpasswd/), in which case I'm not sure what format it expects the salt to be in. The idea that there's such a thing as an "invalid character" is kind of odd... I think you may simply need to use a different tool. I'd look at metasploit modules for this kind of thing. If you're comfortable with virtual machines, fire up a kali VM (or just a live image would do, really).

Comment: Please provide a link to the "sha512whirlpool" algorithm.

Comment: surely your salt doesn't actually contain the quotes [which are causing your salt character fail in comments], the salt I expected to the values *within* the quotes?